# How to catch QComboBox popup close event

Tags: qt, popup, qcombobox

A am using `QComboBox` derived class to show my items. My combo box is read only. But how can I catch the event when popup view of combo box closes?.
For example, when user clicks a mouse button somewhere out of my combo box?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What for do you want this event? If the QComboBox closes without selection nothing changed. The signals given will only be activated when a selection has been made.

If you insist on reading a "close-event", you could subclass `focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent*)` or use an event handler for the focus out event and emit a custom signal. Eventually you want to have a boolean flag set on `hadEditFocus()` before, so you can see if the dropdown would be opened.

Edit:
Eventually it would be easier to subclass and reimplement `showPopup()` and `hidePopup()` as:

```
void MyClass::showPopup() 
{
  QComboBox::showPopup();
  emit signalPopupShown();
}

void MyClass::hidePopup()
{
  QComboBox::hidePopup();
  emit signalPopupHidden();
}
```

but I am not sure if hidePopup() gets called on focus-loose.

Comment: If you only need to know the "clicked" Item, even if it does not change use ``activated(int)`` (or ``activated(QString)``) signal

Comment: I am using such a combo to show items with checkboxes - user can check or uncheck one of them (or more than one), then close combobox (or just click the mouse button outside of it). That is why I need to know that combo box popup is closed.

Comment: And yes - when user click somewhere out of combo box `QComboBox::hidePopup()` **is called** - thank you very much, @Sebastian